# Unable to catch Google cloud storage exception

Tags: flutter

I have a function in my flutter app to download a file from google cloud and store it locally. This function works for existing files, but when I try to download a non existent file, it fails to catch the 'file not found' exception. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out!

```
bool downloadFile({required String localFile, required String remoteFile}) {
  try {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final remoteFileRef = storageRef.child(remoteFile);
    final file = File(localFile);
    final downloadTask = remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file);

    downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot) {
      switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
        case TaskState.running:
          print('TaskState.running');
          break;

        case TaskState.paused:
          print('TaskState.paused');
          break;

        case TaskState.success:
          print('TaskState.success');
          break;

        case TaskState.canceled:
          print('TaskState.canceled');
          break;

        case TaskState.error:
          print('TaskState.error');
          break;
      }
    });
    //} on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (error) {
  } catch (e) {
    print("########### got ex");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen gives you a StreamSubscription so you can handle any error event with the onError method..

Comment: @JilmarXa
That does not help because the exception is thrown in the line before the listener starts. It is this line that is causing the exception, which I'm unable to catch

```
final downloadTask = remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file);
```

Comment: That method has to be a future. Make the function async and wait for a result   final downloadTask =  await remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file); If that method throws you're going to be able to catch it..

Comment: @JilmarXa
thank you for your help. Adding await does indeed catch file not found error. The problem is that when I use
`final downloadTask = remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file);`
I have access to downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot), but as soon as I do
`final downloadTask = await remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file);`
downloadTask.snapshotEvents is undefined. I'm new to flutter/Dart, so I don't understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: Don't worry. You just need to catch the error and throw it again. That action cancel the execution because the file doesn't exist: final downloadTask = await remoteFileRef.writeToFile(file).catchError((e) {
    throw e;
  });  The catch clause has to manage the error you throw